# Is a GridBagLayout the best way to make a panel like this?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm storing some x,y coordinates in the rectangles (JTextFields) and I'd like the JLabels to be in the middle of those two text fields.

Idea:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1StaE.png]

Comment: Try it and see how it goes.  Another way would be to use a vertical BoxLayout, but then you would have to nest panels by using a panel to hold the two text fields. So try both approaches and see which is easier for you. You learn by experimenting.

Comment: Thanks for the another approach seems easier in my mind. Will try both.

Comment: Is that panel resizable? If so, what should happen to vertical space (e.g. more space at bottom, or space equally divided between the three sections)? What should happen if the panel is made wider? Should the input fields (oblongs) be stretched wider, should there be more space between them, more space 'outside' them, or more space evenly divided between both 'between' **&** outside?

Comment: It's not resizable, but if it were I'd like it to just get bigger evenly and keep the same margins between the fields and frame the same.